# Scala capture method of field without whole instance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, higher-order-functions

I had a piece of code that looks like this:

```scala
val foo = df.map(parser.parse) // def parse(str: String): ParsedData = { ... }
```

However, I found out that passes a lambda into Scala that captures `this`, I guess Scala treated code above into:

```scala
val foo = df.map(s => /* this. */parser.parse(s))
```

where my intention to pass lightweight capture. In Java, I'd do `parser::parse`, but that isn't available in Scala.

That does the trick:

```scala
val tmp = parser // split val read from capture; must be in method body
val foo = df.map(tmp.parse)
```

but makes code a little bit more unpleasant. There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398971/method-references-like-in-java-8-in-scala/40399804) by @tiago-henrique-engel that could be used like:

```scala
val tmp = parser.parse _
val foo = df.map(tmp)
```

but it still requires a temporary val.

So, is there a way to pass lightweight capture to `map` without storing it first into some `val` to keep the code clean?

Comment: If your `parser` is not tied to the instance of your class, you may try moving it into an _(companion)_ **object**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that's a great advice, thank you, but I'd prefer to stay away even from capturing companion object.

Comment: @LasphinDmitry I am not 100% sure, but I believe that if it is in an object, it is like a static variable in **Java**. Thus _(I think)_ it will only send it. If not, then it should be the same that what would happen in **Java** anyways.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Great point! Will try it, but still: in case `parser` cannot be stored in singleton object that would not help...

Comment: @LasphinDmitry if it can not be stored in a singleton, then it means your it is tied to the instance, thus you will need all the object to work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez But if it is created and configured by the instance, but not tied after? Of course if it would contain reference to whole reference this cannot be solved, but if, mm: ```val parser = Parser.createWithLotsOfTweaks(... /* without depending on the instance */)```?

Comment: @LasphinDmitry uhm, and can not you change that `val` with a `def`? It will create a new **Parser** each time you use it, but it shouldn't be tied. Anyways, I am far from an expert in **Spark** or **Serialization**, thus at this point i may just be speaking nosense.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it's not a problem. However, my point is when I wanted to store parser in a field there were reasons, like it's heavy to recreate. But I think your ideas about using `def`s or storing `val` in a object could help! My attempts haven't succeeded yet.